# Puppet module that checks to see if a file exists

Tags: puppet

Since there is no easy way in Puppet to check whether a file exists on the agent, I am attempting to write a module that performs this check. However, it is not working as expected. I have done the following :

1. In the modules folder, executed

`puppet module generate root-mymodule`

2. In `mymodule/manifests/file_check.pp`

```
    ..
    ..
      if defined(File["/tmp/test_file"]) {
    ..
    ..
```

However, this does not achieve what I want it to. Apparently it only checks if the file is defined in the catalog. How do I get it to actually check if the file exists ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since there is no easy way in Puppet to check whether a file exists on
>   the agent, I am attempting to write a module that performs this check.

There is no way to test client-side existence of arbitrary files during catalog building when using a master / agent arrangement.  Catalog building happens on the master; there is no way to obtain additional information from the agent during that process.  If instead you are using `puppet apply` then you can use the [`generate`](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/function.html#generate) function, but that's a trap waiting to bite someone who later tries to move your code to a master.

> ```
>       if defined(File["/tmp/test_file"]) {
> ```
>
> [...] does not achieve what I want it to. Apparently it only
>   checks if the file is defined in the catalog.

Yes, that's what `defined()` does.  And it's worse than that, actually: `defined()` can only test whether a declaration of that particular `File` resource has *already* been evaluated.  It cannot tell you about declarations of that resource that may be evaluated later in the same catalog-building run.  Since manifest evaluation order is difficult to predict, `defined` is worse than useless: it is *dangerous*.  Do not use it.

> How do I get it to
>   actually check if the file exists ?

I presume you want to perform such a check in time to use the results to influence catalog building.  This is what *facts* are for.  Puppet offers [multiple approaches to defining and distributing your own facts](https://puppet.com/docs/facter/3.11/custom_facts.html).  For something as simple as testing whether a specific file exists, I'd suggest the "external fact" approach instead of the "custom fact" approach.

But you should also reconsider your premise, which is apparently that a general-purpose mechanism for compile-time testing for the presence of arbitrary files on the agent would be a useful thing to have.  In fact, such tests are rarely useful.  Puppet has better ways of approaching most tasks for which you might otherwise use such a thing, and most of the remaining tasks are usually better not done at all.  If you wanted this for something specific, then I invite you to pose a new question about that particular thing.

Comment: Makes sense that there isn't a way to do this since the catalog is being built. I will attempt the "external fact" route.